# Filtering cities by country in the django admin edit form

Tags: python, django, admin

I'm using [django-cities](https://github.com/coderholic/django-cities) on a small project that lists locations.

The locations model is this:

```
class Location(models.Model):
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    instagram_id = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    new_city = models.ForeignKey(City, related_name='venuecity', null=True, blank=True)

    latitude = models.DecimalField(max_digits=17, decimal_places=14, default=0)
    longitude = models.DecimalField(max_digits=17, decimal_places=14, default=0)
```

the 'city' and 'new_city' fields are temporary while I migrate the data.

My problem is on the admin side of things, how can I filter the city select field by country? The goal is to make it easier for the user to select the correct city when he is adding a new record or editing an existing one.

I looked through django's admin documentation but couldn't figure out how to do this.

Comment: Have you considered creating a custom listfilter ?

Comment: There's a method to list all entries in the admin panel by `name` or any other field. I think starting from that point can help.

Comment: Sorry guys I realized now that I wasn't clear. The problem is that when I am editing a location the select field will show all cities in the world. ideally there would be two select fields: one for country and the other for city.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can customize the form used by the Django admin. In your app, create a form that exhibits the behavior you want. In this case you will probably want to write one that overloads the form's `__init__()` method and adjusts the values of your city field dynamically. E.g.:

```
class LocationAdminForm(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(LocationAdminForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.instance:
            # we're operating on an existing object, not a new one...
            country = self.instance.country
            cities = # get cities from your master countries list...
            self.fields["new_city"] = ChoiceField(choices=cities)
```

Once you have a working ModelForm, you can tell the admin to use it in your admin.py:

```
class LocationAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = LocationAdminForm
```

The admin customization is documented [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.form). An old but still mostly relevant article on dynamic Django forms is [here](http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2008/nov/09/dynamic-forms/).

To do this for NEW records, you will need to implement most of it on the front-end. You will need Javascript code that retrieves and updates the cities  list dynamically as a different country is selected. Your Django app would expose an AJAX view the Javascript can call. It would pass the country and return a simple JSON object of cities, which it would use to update the  element in the form.

Alternatively, a pure server-side solution is possible if you change the workflow. This could work like a "wizard" and ask the user to first select the country. Click next to view step 2 of the wizard with a dynamically generated Django form as above. The [Django wizard app](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/) may be of use.

Comment: Thank you @jdl2003, this is a huge help. Just ran into a small obstacle with the ChoiceField. I get the error "Cannot assign "u'2509408'": "Location.new_city" must be a "City" instance." when i try to update it. As for the new records case, the front-end solution seems to be better. I am using the autocomplete-light app as well which can make it easier for the user.

Comment: Sounds like the ChoiceField needs City objects and you are giving it unicode strings. How are you constructing the cities list in init? Maybe try: City.objects.filter(country__code=self.instance.country).

Comment: When I do that, I get an error that the City object is not iterable. So I was doing cities = City.objects.filter(country__name=self.instance.country).values_list('id', 'name')

Answer (score 0):

I tried the above solution (@jdl2003) but it didn't work (at least in Django 1.8) and I was getting the same error as @bruno-amaral mentioned. I was able to fix the issue like this:

```
#forms.py
from django.forms import ModelForm, ModelChoiceField
from cities_light.models import City

class MyUserAdminForm(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyUserAdminForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.instance:
            country = self.instance.country
            cities = country.city_set.all() if country else City.objects.none()
            self.fields['city'] = ModelChoiceField(queryset=cities)

#admin.py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from myapp.forms import MyUserAdminForm

class MyUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    form = MyUserAdminForm
    UserAdmin.fieldsets += (
        (None, {'fields': ('dob', 'country', 'city')}),
    )
    UserAdmin.list_display += ('country',)

admin.site.register(get_user_model(), MyUserAdmin)
```

Only issue I have now, is that cities list is not getting updated dynamically. I need to first save the country field and after that cities are updated.